# Intellij IDEA plugin - Banner notification

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to modify a custom intellij plugin to improve notification management.

I want to send notification to a Banner﻿, however I found the doc really hard to use to achieve this. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/notifications.html#editor-banner
There is no code example.

Does anyone knows how to do that ?

Thx